# my flutter bottom navigation bar icon buttons is not navigating my app to next screen

Tags: javascript, android, ios, flutter

when I am trying to navigate to another page using bottom navigation bar icons it is not working I don't know why my icon button is not working my screens doesn't have any problems I guess some kind of problem i'm facing with icon buttons I guess help me guys.
github link:https://github.com/ajitzz/perumpallil_public#perumpallil_public2

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:united21/screens/loan.dart';

import '../../../common/color_extension.dart';

class MyBottomNavigation extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyBottomNavigation> createState() => _MyBottomNavigationState();
}

class _MyBottomNavigationState extends State<MyBottomNavigation> {
  int selectTab = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 20),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        children: [
          Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: [
              ColorFiltered(
                colorFilter: const ColorFilter.mode(
                  Colors.black, // Change this color to the desired tint color
                  BlendMode.modulate,
                ),
                child: Image.asset("assets/images/bottom_bar_bg.png"),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectTab = 0;
                        var currentTabView = const LoanScreen();
                      });
                    },
                    icon: Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/home.png",
                      width: 20,
                      height: 20,
                      color:
                          selectTab == 0 ? TColor.redshade500 : TColor.gray30,
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectTab = 1;
                        // ignore: unused_local_variable
                        var currentTabView = const LoanScreen();
                      });
                    },
                    icon: Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/budgets.png",
                      width: 20,
                      height: 20,
                      color:
                          selectTab == 1 ? TColor.redshade500 : TColor.gray30,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectTab = 2;
                        var currentTabView = CalenderView();
                      });
                    },
                    icon: Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/calendar.png",
                      width: 20,
                      height: 20,
                      color:
                          selectTab == 2 ? TColor.redshade500 : TColor.gray30,
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectTab = 3;
                        var currentTabView = CardsView();
                      });
                    },
                    icon: Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/creditcards.png",
                      width: 20,
                      height: 20,
                      color:
                          selectTab == 3 ? TColor.redshade500 : TColor.gray30,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoanScreen()));
            },
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: TColor.secondary.withOpacity(0.25),
                    blurRadius: 10,
                    offset: const Offset(0, 4))
              ], borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 32,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade900,
                child: IconButton(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoanScreen.id);
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.currency_rupee_sharp,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to navigate to next page but it doesn't work and it doesn't showing any errors also instead icon button I tried to navigate directly it worked ...?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are only assigning the widgets to your `currentTabView`

You should update it in your parent widget too. Add this to your parent widget

```
void update(Widget widget){
     setState((){
        currentTabView = widget;
     })
}
```

pass it to you bottomNavigationState like so:
`MyBottomNavigation(update);`

In your widget add the parameter:

```
class MyBottomNavigation extends StatefulWidget {

  final Function function
  const MyBottomNavigation(this.function);

  @override
  State<MyBottomNavigation> createState() => _MyBottomNavigationState();
}
```

Now, inside your IconButton do it like so:

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: () {
     setState(() {
       selectTab = 0;
       function(const LoanScreen());
     });
  }
  icon: Image.asset(
     assets/images/home.png",
     width: 20,
     height: 20,
     color:
     selectTab == 0 ? TColor.redshade500 : TColor.gray30,
   ),
),
```

Comment: I did exactly like you said still it is not working if you could  help me with it I tried with cat got also not getting fixed ill share you the  project link: https://github.com/ajitzz/perumpallil_public#perumpallil_public2

Comment: @ajithDrive you did update `currentTabView` in your home_screen.dart but you didn't use it. Where do you want it? because i see ListView on the scaffold of Home_screen.dart